# How to link web parts?

Tags: 2007, web-part

I have a page with 2 web parts.

One of them is a list, where the users can add an item (their personal info).

Once they have entered their personal info, it should show up in the 2nd list (with the option to edit)

So in the end, users should be able to see the info of all the users in the 1st list, but only their own in the 2nd list.

Which approach should I use for this? Should both web parts be lists? On the first list I have a "Created By" column that is automatically set to the user's full name when they enter the info, if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually quite easy. Set up a list with your desired columns and create two views. Configure the first view to display all list data according to your preferences, this will be your base view for the first web part.

Then configure a second view that filters the list items using the Created By-column, to do this set a filter option "Created By equals [Me]". Then go to your page, drop this list as a web part two times on the page and configure the web parts with these views.

There you have it, two web part besides each other, one displaying the full list data, the other one only items created by the current user.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add audience targeting to the second web part/list. So a user would only be able to see the information belonging to him.

Comment: How would I do this? Do you mean in Edit mode, selecting a specific target or is there another "add audience targeting" option ?

Comment: you can target the items in the second list to the respective owners (via the list settings->audience targeting). This would automatically trim the UI in the second web part.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. Audience targeting seems to be a global setting that you set to the whole page, but inside I have the webpart and the list. How am I defining that the 2nd web part should be filtereD?

Comment: I hope you have a second list. You can go to that list and apply audience targeting to the items in there via the list settings.